# Getting Exception when trying to get pattern data using loop

Tags: java, regex

I am reading mail using JAVA MAIL API. I am getting **SKU** data perfectly till now as there was only one **SKU** in mail , For ex:

**Data in Mail :**

```
SKU: TX1234-3322

Quantity: 1

Price: $7.95
```

**My Code to get SKU is :**

```
public static List<String> SKUData = new ArrayList<String>();

if(Content.contains("SKU:"))
                   {
                       Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("SKU\\s*:\\s*(\\S*)");
                       Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(Content);
                       if(matcher.find()) {  //we've found a match
                           FinalSKU = matcher.group(1);
                       }

SKUData.add(FinalSKU);
```

Above all working fine till now , But from now I am getting **multiple SKUs** in single mail , So for ex:

```
SKU: TX1234-3322

Quantity: 1

Price: $7.95

SKU: TX9090-8888

Quantity: 1

Price: $6.25
```

**So I tried code :**

```
for(int k=1;k<10;k++)
{
 if(Content.contains("SKU:"))
                       {
                           Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("SKU\\s*:\\s*(\\S*)");
                           Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(Content);
                           if(matcher.find()) {  //we've found a match
                               FinalSKU = matcher.group(k);
                           }

    SKUData.add(FinalSKU);
}
```

But this solution is not working. I am getting exception when my loop reach at **k=2**.

How can I get data using pattern when same pattern data is there multiple times.

Comment: use `while` instead of `if`, since the regex finds more than one match.

Comment: Read the javadoc of Matcher.find(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29. Iterate until it returns false. Don't use a loop that goes arbitrarily from 0 to 10.

Comment: Add the stacktrace please

Comment: @Jens - `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missunderstanding `Matcher.group()` a little bit. You need to call `Matcher.find()` multiple times to find multiple results and then read `Matcher.group(1)` for all of them.

One more thing to note: Do **not** call `Pattern.compile` in a loop, not even in a method. The compilation of a pattern is expensive, you might not notice, but once you call this more often, you'll noticeable slow down your program. Make it a `private static final` and reuse the once-compiled pattern.

A matching-group in a pattern is everything between `(` and `)` (as long as it is not escaped). So as your pattern is `SKU\\s*:\\s*(\\S*)`, the only matching-group you have is `(\\S*)`. You could - of course - have more groups if you'd need more values out of this line, but since the ID (or whatever it might be) is the only thing you're interested in, you only need this one group.

You can read more about matching groups (also called capturing groups) [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: So Matcher.group(1) will be always `1`?

Comment: In this example yes. In others it might be something else. I'll edit to clarify what a group is.

Comment: I am trying to get SKU, QTY and Price , So should I use 3 while loop? for every match finder? Because If I use only 1 `While` and put all 3 in it , I am getting only SKU data correct, But QTY and Price data seems not updated. it is storing 1st data 3 times in array.

Comment: Yes, either you use three loops, or, __iff__ they are _always_ formatted like this (SKU, two breaks, Quantity, two breaks, Price), you could use a single pattern to get them all (with three match-groups).

Comment: If I use while loop , it is getting data of same SKU again and again and not getting out of it.